# Is there an complet example of Spring Boot 3.1.1 (Spring Security 6.1.1) for Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

All I found in documentation for Oauth 2 is partial document

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html

There are good example for Spring Boot 2.x (Spring Security 5) like this one
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_logout

The approach for Spring Security 5 cause in 403 in all post actions

Looking for a full Spring Boot 3.1.1 example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can't be "one complete example", there are many depending on your scenario:

- **servlet** (WebMvc) or **reactive** (Webflux) application?
- is the Spring application an **OAuth2 client** (oauth2Login, secured with session cookies and CSRF protection, and redirecting unauthorized requests to login) or is it an **OAuth2 resource server** (no "login", secured with access token, having sessions as well as CSRF protection disabled, and returning 401 to unauthorized requests)?
- is it "single" or "multi" tenant (does it accept identities issued by more than just one authorization server)?
- is it **decoding JWTs** or **introspecting opaque tokens**?

I cover all these use cases (and more) [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials)